# how to search rdf with sparql using java?

Tags: java, rdf, sparql

I am doing project in semantic web where i use SPARQL to query rdf data.  I used java in netbeans  and my problem is my program runs,inputs the rdf file and the query executes but the **WHERE area of my query is not considered**. (i.e) i get a *empty table as output*

Can you please tel me any suggestions of **SPARQL syntax in JAVA** to retrieve all name,phone number from rdf file

Comment: can you post some sample data and also an example of one of those queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"WHERE area of my query is not considered. (i.e) i get a empty table as output"

I doubt the `WHERE` clause is not being considered. An empty table suggests a) you have no data or b) your query has no matches.

Retrieving all names and phone number depends on the vocabulary used, but the most common by far is [foaf](http://www.foaf-project.org/):

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?name, ?number
WHERE
{
    ?person foaf:name ?name .
    ?person foaf:phone ?number .
}
```

We need more information, so here's some generic advice:

1. Try `SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }`. Is that getting results? If not, try...
2. Try `SELECT * WHERE { graph ?g { ?s ?p ?o } }`. Is that getting results?

If neither are working you may have issues with you data. If only the second gets result you check you are querying graphs.

This will give you a good idea about what you have loaded either way. If it looks ok:

1. Remove an element of your `WHERE` clause.
2. If you still get no results go to 1.
3. If you get results you have found an issue with your query.

You can also try replacing terms with variables. Working this way might help track down which elements are causing the query to fail.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply sir.Tried with the first query and i got the output sir.But the second query gives me only a empty table.and tried various queries,but empty table is only got.Here is my rdf file                                                        <?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:foaf="http://www.resume.fake/foaf#">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.resume.fake/foaf/Sheba">
<foaf:name>Sheba</foaf:name>
<foaf:phne>8872443601</foaf:phne></rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>

Comment: Problem is in my java code i hope so.here is my java code sir.please help me.                                                        
String queryString ="PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> " +"PREFIX foaf: <http://www.resume.fake/foaf/#> " +
"SELECT ?name  ?number WHERE { ?x foaf:name ?name . ?x foaf:phone ?number .}";
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query,model);ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);

Comment: You spelled 'phone' wrong. <foaf:phne> should be <foaf:phone> in your rdf file.

Comment: Changed and tried it sir.But i still get an empty table in output.

Comment: You have the wrong prefix for foaf, and because the one you have is relative your queries will break. Use http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/

Comment: sir,but still i am not getting output for this query.  SELECT * WHERE { graph ?g { ?s ?p ?o } } .what may be the reason for this ?

Comment: It just means you don't have any data in named graphs: it was a check to see whether you have any data loaded at all. Sometimes people query the default graph (no `graph` keyword) but have stored their data in a named graph.